# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime Error Code -1073741795

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow. I have installed tensorflow without GPU as my machine won't support gpu version.
I have installed it in portable winpython.

Here is my stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import
     return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
   File "D:\Life_In_IEM\Project\Predicting_Riot\Mine_Data\WPy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
   File "D:\Life_In_IEM\Project\Predicting_Riot\Mine_Data\WPy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
     _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
   File "D:\Life_In_IEM\Project\Predicting_Riot\Mine_Data\WPy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
     return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
   File "D:\Life_In_IEM\Project\Predicting_Riot\Mine_Data\WPy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
     return _load(spec) 
  ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```